# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire image not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

This morning I try to install my application on my iPhone after debugging on my Simulator and suddenly I faced up with this error I'm using iOS 13.3.1 and I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and this error happened on all of my projects out of no where and I tried every solutions from stack overflow questions and nothing works so anyone knows how to fix this?

I am using cocoapods

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/845A676F-BED3-4F3F-9495-FBBCF1E56A06/Music
>   Time.app/Music Time   Reason: image not found

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580003683

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some search I figured it out . It is new issue on ios 13.3.1 that basically apple wont allow us to install apps on actual device with free developer account (only with embeded frameworks) as workaround comment 
use_frameworks! 
On podfile and use
use_modular_headers! 
instead .

Comment: Use latest version of Alamofire or just update to ios 13.4 beta